# Origin of ++ postfix and prefix

Tags: c#, c++, c

Who knows about origin and reasons of ++ postfix and sufix form. I know that they are available even in C. But who invented them; perhaps even in other languages?

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask philosophical questions about the history of specific programming language features.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a question easily answerd by looking at a wikipedia entry on the subject.

Comment: As usually I asked google about my questions. Today discovered wikipedia

Comment: In hindsight, I rather like this question. I've edited it; hopefully to improve a little. (And so I can convert my downvote to an upvote ;-) )

Comment: @Bathsheba although, the question shows no research effort (reason to downvote) and I don't understand how it would be useful (reason for downvote).

Comment: I found the answers it generated informative. And it might come in handy in a pub quiz one day.

Comment: Just found reason for ++ operator: ++ is easier to write, then variable = variable + 1;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Citing from the [Wikipedia article on the B programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%28programming_language%29):

> *"B also introduced the increment and decrement operators (`++` and `--`); Their prefix or postfix position determines whether the value is taken prior or post alteration of the operand."*

I see no point in duplicating the whole Wikipedia article. Just go there for more details.

By the way, while the B language might have *introduced* these specific forms for the increment and decrement operations, it's unlikely that B also *invented* the operations themselves. I suspect that even early CPUs had dedicated increment and decrement operations (next to the more general add and subtract operations).

Comment: @Bathsheba - note that question is tagged with C#/C++ (along with C) and there is no way `++` is atomic there due to ability to have custom operators...

Comment: In assembler for x86 processors there is function INC, so ++ can be implemented as atomic

Answer (score 8):

From Dennis M. Ritchie, [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html),  HOPL II, 1993:

> For example, B introduced generalized assignment operators, using x=+y to add y to x. The notation came from Algol 68 [Wijngaarden 75] via McIlroy, who had incorporated it into his version of TMG. (In B and early C, the operator was spelled =+ instead of += ; this mistake, repaired in 1976, was induced by a seductively easy way of handling the first form in B's lexical analyzer.)
>
> Thompson went a step further by inventing the ++ and -- operators, which increment or decrement; their prefix or postfix position determines whether the alteration occurs before or after noting the value of the operand.